# How to combine a cell array of cell arrays to a single cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, concatenation, cell-array

I have a dynamic cell array of cell arrays (of strings) and I want to combine it into a single cell array of strings.

Example:

```
Columns 1 through 4
{4x1 cell}    {9x1 cell}    {8x1 cell}    {10x1 cell}
```

I want to concatenate the inner cells, and the result be one cell array of the form

```
{31x1 cell}.
```

How can I concatenate into one cell array **without for loop**?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using [`vertcat`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html)...

```
cellarr = {cell(4,1), cell(9,1), cell(8,1), cell(10,1)};
merged = vertcat(cellarr{:});
```